# Como eliminar unicamente los primero elementos de un array dentro de otro array

Tags: python

Vamos a suponer que tengo los siguientes array :

```
array1=["A","B","F","A","B"]
array2=["A","F"]
```

Necesito eliminar los valores de `array2` de `array1` sin eliminar todos los elementos de `array2` que esta dentro de `array1`.

En otras palabras, el resultado tiene que ser :

```
array3=["B","A","B"]
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: `nuevo = [x for x in array1 if not array2 or (x != array2[0] and array2.pop(0))]`

Comment: Hola @Vignon, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías comenzar mirando la sección [ask]. Este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas. ¿Qué has intentado para solucionarlo? ¿Dónde tienes el problema exactamente?

Comment: ¿Es importante el orden? ¿qué resultado esperas para `arrFull=["F","B","A","A","B"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto, puedes utilizar el siguiente código :

```
arrFull = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
arrRemove = ["A", "D"]

for i in arrRemove:
    if i in arrFull:
        arrFull.remove(i)
        arrRemove.remove(i)
```

**Explicación**

Primero de todo, se ha declarado el array con nombre `arrFull` dónde están todos los elementos. En tu caso, este es el equivalente a tu array con nombre `array1`.

```
arrFull = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Seguido de esto, declaramos el siguiente array llamado `arrRemove` dónde se almacenan los elementos que queremos eliminar. Este es el equivalente a tu `array2`.

```
arrRemove = ["A", "D"]
```

Una vez con las arrays declaradas, sencillamente debes de ejecutar un bucle `for` sobre `arrRemove` *(aunque podrías hacerlo con cualquiera de las dos arrays cambiando los valores)*

```
for i in arrRemove:
      # Código
```

De esta manera, vamos iterar todos los valores de la array `arrRemove` como un simple bucle for.

Ahora, por cada elemento, debemos comprobar si este existe en el array donde queremos eliminar estos elementos (`arrFull`) para esto, sencillamente utilizamos la condición `if` tal y como se muestra :

```
if i in arrFull:
```

Si la condición `if` se cumple,
significa que el valor interado (`i`) existe en `arrFull` por lo que sencillamente deberemos de eliminar este valor en el array `arrFull` haciendo uso de la función `remove(X)` tal y como se ve en el bucle donde aquí te adjunto más información sobre esta función.

```
if i in arrFull:
    arrFull.remove(i)
    arrRemove.remove(i)
```

Tras esto, se eliminan todos los elementos de array `arrRemove` que existen en `arrFull`.

Comment: Te he publicado una respuesta "extendida" para que entiendas la básica de esto ya que realmente, es algo sencillo. Si por cualquier cosa necesitaras más información o aclaración sobre algún punto escribe un comentario! Un saludo !

Comment: esta respuesta no es lo que buscava
vamos a suponer que tengo 
arrFull = ["A", "B", "A", "C", "D" , "D"]
arrRemove = ["A", "D"]
 y quiero eliminar unicamente arrRemove=["A", "D"] y o seja que el nuevo
sea arrFull=[ "B", "A", "C",  "D"]  como lo haria

Comment: Entiendo, te acabo de actualizar la respuesta, checkea la condición `if` de nuevo y comentame si es esto lo que necesitas para que en caso de ser así, añada un par mas de líneas de explicación.

Comment: Por lo que acabo de comprobar, la actualización de la pregunta es exactamente lo que buscas.

Comment: Porque sale este error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'remove' ?

Comment: Consulta [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197943/numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-remove) aquí está la solución al problema con el atributo remove y numpy. Este es un conflicto que se crea con la librería numpy que tienes importada.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Me puede indicar otra alternativa del metodo "choises" en python. Porque necesito seleccionar  n numero dentro de un array  arr pero que no vuelva a selecionar una  posicion dentro del array que ja escogiu